# append new rows and input tags using jQuery

Tags: jquery, append

I have a web application that has set to navigate its input fields using Enter key too. In addition, I have a control in my forms that appends new rows to a table that contains my input fields.

```
<select name="more" id="more" style="width:50px">
   <option value="0">0</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
```

And this what I used for appending new rows containing input fields.

```
$('#more').change(function(e) {
    var current_rows = ($('#myTable tr').length)-1;
    current_rows = parseInt(current_rows);
    var more = $('#more').val();
    more = parseInt(more);
    if (more != '0') {
        for (i = current_rows+1 ; i <= current_rows+more ; i++) {
           // rows HTML tags here as content
           $('#myTable tr:last').after(content);
        }
    }
    $('#more').val('0');
});
```

Imagine that I have 5 rows at the first time. Whenever I press Enter, the cursor changes its position from the current field to the next one. But when I append new rows and their input fields, anything will not happen from the 6th row. Even, it can not fetch the key code for the Enter using my previous code.

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
// do something
}
```

What is the matter ?

Comment: Could you post more of the code, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in jQuery 1.7+ then use `on` or `delegate` instead. It is more efficient than old methods. Here I monitor the table for click events on table cells. When an event occurs I add `clicked!` to the table cell. This works for both the initial table cells and added ones.

http://jsfiddle.net/WBxQz/1/

```
$('#more').change(function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this).val(); i++) {
        $('#myTable').append('<tr><td></td></tr>');
    }
});

$('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
    $(this).html('clicked!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you load other rows dynamically into you DOM .Maybe the "Live" method of Jquery can help you

```
$("#myTable tr").live("keypress",function (e){

if(e.keyCode == 13)
    //Do somthing

});
```

if this solution did not work , comment me to edit it

Good luck, Ali

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7 `live` is deprecated. It is also not recommended for jQuery 1.4.2 or later. You should use `delegate` instead.

Comment: I'm sure the reason is what you said. But your code did not work to solve it.

Comment: did you use the delegate instead of live method ?

Comment: Thank you Ali and mrtsherman.
Your answers helped me to solve it.
Finally I can do what I needed using the code below:

    $("#myTable").delegate("input","keypress",function(e) {
    // do something
    });

Comment: according to mrtsherman saying , live is deprecated
COOL! happy for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve my problem using Ali's and mrtsherman's suggestions.

```
$("#myTable").delegate("input","keypress",function(e) {
    // do something
})
```

Thank you Ali and Mrtsherman.